# using media queries @print isnt previewing the whole page

Tags: css, media-queries

on my webpage i have table that is very lengthy in data.

Like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Column 1   |    Column 2   | Column 3  | Clumn 4  |
---------------------------------------------------
  data 1   |    data 2     |  data 3   | data 4   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using media queries for smaller devices so that it goes like this:

Column 1: data 1
Column 2: data 2
Column 3: data 3
Column 4: data 4

Thing is, there is huge amounts of data on this one webpage. Im using `@media print` in a new style sheet for printing.

The problem is though that its only showing about 3 pages, and I can see there are plenty more data that needs to be shown. I know the link to the sheet is working because its still doing the other styles like font color etc. Also, there is a border around my page. In the print preview, the border is not closed off. So I know there is more to show.

I've also done `body, html {width: 100; height: 100%; display: block;}` and its made no difference.

Does someone have any suggestions? Thanks.

```
@media print { 
/*Generic styling */

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the 100% height from body and HTML, and also avoid all other `height` settings, making height dependant on the contents.

Comment: there are no other height settings, and originally I didnt have height or width on the html or body but I only did that because someone suggested it another question. It doesnt work either way.